# how to extract TODOS from java source files

Tags: java, latex

Hi
I need a [xxxreport](http://code.google.com/p/xxxreport/) like program to generate a todo list from java source files (in other words extract all //TODO comments) idealy to a  latex list 
or are there any other good java 2 latex tools ?
Thanks

Comment: Eclipse has the option to see all TODOS , FIXME, etc. You can copy them to wherever you want. This is more a tip if you don't find any dedicated software to do it, so I made a comment with this and not an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive made a simple python script which achieves this task thanks for the grep suggestion

```
 


#!/usr/bin/python
import commands
import sys
path= sys.argv[1]

a=commands.getoutput("grep -e //.*todo -e //.*TODO -R "+path).split("\n")
print "\\begin{itemize}"
lastFileName=""
firstItem=1;
open=0
for ln in a:

    ln=ln.replace("\t","").replace("//","").replace("{","").replace("}","").replace("\\","")
    if lastFileName!= ln[0:ln.find(":")]:

        lastFileName= ln[0:ln.find(":")]
        if firstItem!=1:
            print " \\end{itemize}"     
            open=1  
        print "\\item "+lastFileName+" \n   \\begin{itemize}"
        firstItem=0
        open=1

    print " \\item  "+ln[ln.find(":"):len(ln)]


if open:
    print " \\end{itemize}"
print "\\end{itemize}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered "grep -R" with post-massaging with awk or perl into the final form?

Comment: yes that is always an option I was just curious if there is an application for this. still thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse generates a TODO list. Look at the Tasks view.

Comment: I know I was looking for a command line tool still thanks for your answer